# Get id of selected anchor tag on click and set html of another div accordingly

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 anchor (a) tags, all sharing a single div element to act upon. See my html below. Basically, when you click on anchor tag 1, I want it to fill the div with id="fillDiv" with html. When you click the second anchor tag, it should wipe that #fillDiv and replace it with new html. How do I set up such a functions. Here is my attempt

HTML:

```
<div>
<a id="a1" href="javascript: changeDiv();">tag1</a>
<a id="a2" href="javascript: changeDiv();">tag2</a>
<a id="a3" href="javascript: changeDiv();">tag3</a>
</div>

<div id="fillDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
function changeDiv(){
     if changeDiv().is('#a1'){
         document.getElementById('fillDiv').html('<div>filling 1</div>');
         }

     elseif
         changeDiv().is('#a2'){
         document.getElementById('fillDiv').html('<div>filling 2</div>');
         }

     elseif
         changeDiv().is('#a3'){
         document.getElementById('fillDiv').html('<div>filling 3</div>');
         }
}
```

Please NOTE: I do not want to use a show/hide div function, it is important to me that the filling Div is only a single div, not coupled with 2 other divs having display:none properties at start.

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html remains the same, just remove `onclick` event and try below js -

```
$("a").click(function(){
   if($(this).attr("id") == "a1") {
      $("#fillDiv").html("<div>filling 1</div>")
   }
   else if($(this).attr("id") == "a2") {
      $("#fillDiv").html("<div>filling 2</div>")
   }
   else if($(this).attr("id") == "a3") {
      $("#fillDiv").html("<div>filling 3</div>")
   }
});
```

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/cPZfX/

If your id are gonna be like `a1, a2, a3` then you make a loop and do more optimization.

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you so much. I have a silly question for you. Is the $ declaration only part of the Jquery library or is it plain javascript? Also, I assume the javascript in this example should be included right after the html in the markup right? When must it be in the head and when not(generally speaking)?

Comment: yes the $ declaration is part of jquery here. You will have to include jquery file in your `<head>`. And it will be better to call the script that I have written after your html is created i.e. before `</body>` will be good. Because the event is binded only when the element is present in the DOM. Well after reading @Interfector's answer I think if you are not using jquery in your code then not to use my solution. Try his.

Answer (score 2):

The code bellow follows your example, but you can make it more generic, based on the id.

```
var element;
var handler = function( event ) {
    var target = document.getElementById('fillDiv');
    switch this.id {
       case 'a1':
         target.html('<div>filling 1</div>');
         break;
       case 'a2':
         target.html('<div>filling 2</div>');
         break;
       case 'a3':
         target.html('<div>filling 3</div>');
         break;
    }
};
for ( var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
  element = document.getElementById( 'a' + i );
  element.addEventListener( 'click', handler );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I really like the fact that is is pure Javascript, but I'm not sure how to call the function from the a tags. I assume it must be the Onclick="" event, but how do I configure it?

Comment: The click event is configured in the lower part of the solution, the for loop. This where I attach the click event to the a tags identified by the ai pattern, where i is a value between 1 and 3 (like in your question). Now, the handler variable is actually the function that gets called when the event gets triggered. This is where you should add your logic. I just added a switch statement there as an example.